# Is it compatible to create bootable USB from M1 Mac to be installed on an Intel Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to understand the compatibility between Intel Mac and M1 Mac.

I have an old Mac that is somehow having issues with the utility and I am not able to get the MacBook setup. Then I am trying to create a bootable USB from my MacBook Pro M1. But I see a circle with a cross when trying to install it on the Intel Mac.

Intel **MacBook Air** is from 2017 and **M1 MacBook Pro** is from 2022.

I made the bootable to **Ventura 13**.

Comment: I have not tried this on an M1 Mac but there is a command you run in terminal using *createinstallmedia* (do a search for that command, detailed instructions are readily available) that will do exactly what you think it does. Just double clicking on the installer won't work, as you have found. If the *createinstallmedia* command doesn't work either you may have to find an Intel Mac to create the install media.

Comment: The 2017 MBA is not supported on Ventura: it can only run Monterey.

Comment: Apple did not make any M1 MacBook Pros in 2022. Apple did make a M2 MacBook Pro 13-Inch in 2022 and several M1 MacBook Pros in 2021.

Comment: I've gone the other way any number of times, made a USB stick on an Intel Mac and used it on a M1 Mac.  There's no selectivity.